# Relation Algebra in SQL

Tags: sql, algebra, relational

I'm trying to write a sql query into relational algebra. If I have:

- **Hotel(hotelNo,hotelName,hotelStreet,hotelCity,hotelState)**
- **Room(roomNo, hotelNo, type, price)**
- **guest (guestNo, guestName, guestStreet, guestCity)**
- **Booking(hotelNo, guestNo, datFrom, dateTo, roomNo)**

I'm wondering how to write what rooms are occupied in 3-17-2014 in relational database

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from hotel h 
inner join room r on h.hotelno=r.hotelno 
inner join booking b on b.hotelno=r.hotelno  and b.roomno = r.roomno
inner join guest g on g.guestno = b.guestno
where '<yourdate>' between b.datFrom and b.dateTo
```

try this

Comment: I think what OP means to say is: write the query using `Relational algebra calculas` like `Tuple Calculas` and `Domain Calculas`; and not using SQL.